# How to determine which TCP/UDP ports are being opened by a given process (linux)?

Tags: tcp, port, process, netstat, lsof

I know how to do the opposite (find out what process has a given port open) using lsof or netstat, but extensive research on Google hasn't helped me solve the reverse problem.

I know I could use "netstat -np" combined with some grep and sed, but it seems hacky.  Is there a reversed version of "lsof -i tcp:80" that will show me all the local ports opened by a given process?

Comment: I don't see why pipeline filtering is "hacky". It's how Unix was designed to be used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the man page, you'll find that you can use the `-p` option to specify a process id, and the `-i` option to limit the display to internet domain sockets (`-i4` for just ipv4 and `-i6` for just ipv6).  So if you string them together...

```
lsof -p <pid> -i
```

...you get not quite what you want, because by default `lsof` will *or* together your requests.  So add the `-a` (*and*) flag...

```
lsof -p <pid> -a -i
```

...and you'll get a list of the IPv4 sockets open by the specified process id.

Comment: And if you only care about the TCP ports the process is LISTENing to replace `-i` with `-iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`

Answer (score 1):

> I know I could use `netstat -np` combined with some grep and sed, but
>   it seems hacky.

How about this:

```
# netstat --inet -nlp | grep <processname>
```

> Is there a reversed version of `lsof -i tcp:80` that will show me all
>   the local ports opened by a given process?

```
# lsof -c <processname> | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment to let me know why.